# Can I export a list from SharePoint 2007 and then import to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: stsadm, export, import

I have a user that has requested we copy her Shared Documents library from SharePoint 2007 team site to an existing SharePoint 2010 team site.

Can this be accomplished with OOB STSADM export/import commands?

Thanks,

Hank

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it with export/import.

Depending on how complex that doc lib is, you might want to copy that files manually or migrate the database that contains the library.

Maybe (maybe, because I have not tried it) you can save the list as a template and modify it in a way that you can use it in SP2010. But I don't know if it is supported. You have to...

- Rename the .STP file to .CAB
- Extract the manifest.xml
- Search for "ProductVersion"
- Change the value to "4"
- Include the manifest.xml into the .CAB (you can use "makecab.exe" for that)
- Change the extension back to .STP and upload it into the "_catalogs/lt"

Found it [here](http://ebbypeter.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/how-to-convert-a-sharepoint-2007-list-template-stp-to-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by AlexPoint, you can't do it with stsadm. There are 3rd party tools to do this, but Bamboo Solutions has a pretty good overview of [migrating lists](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/11/17/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-migrate-a-single-list-from-sp-2007-to-sp-2010.aspx) from 2007 to 2010 without them. AlexPoint shows what I think is the simplest method above. Note, though, that if you have a lot of items in the list (thousands), it might not work. The other three options are (hit the link above for details):

1. Use an access table (requires access. You'll lose created/modified info)
2. detach the db (This is the most labor intensive and will fail if you used a fab40 template for the list in my experience)
3. Use powershell